# Android App Socket Creation (for Host Reachability) waits indefinitely while Web App works perfectly fine when connected via System Proxy

Tags: android, sockets, networking, proxy

I am facing a tricky situation while working on a restricted network. Though I have my System Proxy Set to connect to my Web Server, Below are the two different behaviors observed from Web Browser and from Android Sockets .

1) With Proxy set, The **Web Browser Request for the my server URL (host:port) goes well** and I get **200 OK** with valid Response Data from the Server. 

2) With **Android App**, I do **Host Reachability** check before making my Connection Request.  In Host reach-ability check , I create a **java.net Socket** and if it returns without any exception i consider my host as reachable. PSB for code snippet.

```
public static boolean isHostReachable(String hostname, int port) {
    boolean isReachable = false;

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
      socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
      isReachable = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      .....
    } finally {
      ....
    }

  return isReachable;
}
```

The *whole logic of Host Reachability check works fine when in work from unrestricted network (lets say my home network).*

The **problem comes in the Host Reachability Socket Call** , when I run my app from a restricted network (with Proxy Set to access my Server). Here my Socket Creation call does not return leading to host reach ability failure !!

**There is a clear discrepancy between the browser and my app behavior in restricted network!!**

***My Question*** : While the Web Appllication works perfectly fine, **What can be reason for the failure of above Socket Creation from Android** leading to my Host Reachability failure  in restricted network (with Proxy set in System Preference) and any suggestion for me to overcome this ?